# I would like to replace the text in a column from "300-21-2" to "300-21-02" with one query

Tags: mysql, sql, replace, varchar

Is there an easy way to replace all the text in a VARCHAR 255 column from "300-21-2" to "300-21-02" with one query?
Thank you.

Comment: Does that column really need to be a varchar(255)?

Comment: You want to update the whole table with this pattern ??

Comment: The pattern is the same? 3numbers-2numbers-anything?

Comment: Yes we'd like to keep it a varchar. Yes the whole table. Sometimes it's 2numbers-2numbers-anything / 4char-2numbers-anything / 3char-2numbers-anything / 2char-2numbers-anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern is always the same NNN-NN-N then what you need is:

```
update tablex
   set column = concat( substr(column,1,7), lpad(substr(column,8),2,'0') )
```

see it at fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f59fe/1

**EDIT** As the op showed the pattern

```
update tablex
   set column = CONCAT(  
         substring_index(col, '-',1), '-',
         lpad(substring_index(substring_index(col, '-',-2), '-', 1),2,'0'), '-',
         lpad(substring_index(col, '-',-1), 2, '0') )
```

If you like to convert the first set like `300` to `00300` as your pattern you add the lpad as this: `lpad(substring_index(col, '-',1),5,'0')`

This should be a lot easier if mysql has support to regex replace, but as it hasnt you have to work with the strings:

- from this value: '300-02-1'
- from `substring_index(col, '-',1)` I'm getting: `300`
- from `substring_index(substring_index(col, '-',-2), '-', 1)` I'm getting `02` I did this because just put the `substring_index(col, '-',2)` gave me `300-02` so, i got it from right to left (`-2`) then i get the first
- and substring_index(col, '-',-1) it bring me 1 because it gets the value from right to left

Then I just concatenate it all formatting the ones I want.

Comment: We have different patterns NNNN-NN-N / NNNN-NN-NN / NNN-NN-N / NNN-NN-NN / NN-NN-N / NN-NN-NN. But what you gave is good I think we can work with that, thank you.

Comment: Then the only pattern is the `-` and the tree numbers between then.

Comment: You will need to use the `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with a combination of CONCAT and LPAD functions. If you want to see I can edit my answer. Let me know.

Answer (score 1):

This is basic SQL

```
UPDATE tablename
SET columnname = '300-21-02'
WHERE columnname = '300-21-2'
```